# How to install Cartopy to python-3.5 on linux-32

Tags: linux, python-3.x, 32-bit, cartopy

When I try to install it throught conda

```
conda install -c scitools cartopy
```

apper message:

> Fetching package metadata ......... Solving package specifications: .
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current
>   linux-32 channels: 
>     - cartopy
>
> Close matches found; did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
> cartopy: astropy
> ```
>
> You can search for packages on anaconda.org with
>
> ```
> anaconda search -t conda cartopy
> ```

When I run

```
anaconda search -t conda cartopy
```

appear new message

> Packages:
>        Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
>
> ```
>  ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
>  CISTools/cartopy          |          | conda           | osx-64         
>                                       : A library providing cartographic tools for python
>  ChrisBarker/cartopy       |          | conda           | osx-64
> ```

...

> ```
>  vsheremet/cartopy         |   0.11.2 | conda           | linux-32
> ```
>
> Found 22 packages

And when I try to use one of them - for example

```
conda install -c moghimis cartopy
```

I receive

> Fetching package metadata ......... Solving package specifications:
>   ....
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - cartopy
>     - python 3.5*
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

How can I install this package to my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, the problem here is there is no build of cartopy available on [anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=cartopy) that meets the combination of `linux-32` and `py35`. There are some `linux-32` builds available (from Unidata and pelson, for example) and some `py35` builds (from IOOS, for example), but none that do both.

This is because...

- `py35` is reasonably new, so there are relatively few people building against it at the moment, and
- `linux-32` is now reasonably old, so few people still build packages for it.

The easiest solution is to change one of your dependencies. For example, if you can change your Python requirement to `py34` then you can use the [Unidata](https://anaconda.org/Unidata/cartopy) `linux-32` build of cartopy. Note that this is an older build of cartopy, however, at v0.13.0 compared to the latest release of v0.14.3.

If you want a challenge another solution to this would be to build cartopy for yourself! The recipe (what the final cartopy version is built from) can be found in a GitHub organisation called conda-forge (at https://github.com/conda-forge/cartopy-feedstock). There are some instructions on updating a recipe here: https://conda-forge.github.io/#update_recipe.